# php returning undefined in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I have tried to make search suggestions like google...

i created a table tags and a single column tag and it has some tags stored in it
but the problem is when i type nothing or something that is in the DB i get undefined as return

but when i type something that is not in DB i get sorry [which is correct]

i am using Ajax

my php code

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';

        $searchvalue=$_GET['searchvalue'];

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myweb") or die("error connecting db");
        $sqlresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tag FROM tags where tag like '".$searchvalue."%'");
        $suggests="";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult))
        {
            $suggests=$suggests.$row.',';
        }

        //$suggarray=explode(",",$suggests);

        if(strlen($suggests)>0)
        {
            echo "found";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry! for ".$searchvalue;
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    echo '</response>';
?>
```

JavaScript for ajax

```
// JavaScript for search ajax

var xmlHttp= createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    //alert("create obj");
   var xmlHttp;

   if(window.ActiveXObject){
      try{
         xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(e){
            xmlHttp =false;
            }
      }else{
         try{
            xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch(e){
               xmlHttp =false;
               }
         }
      if(!xmlHttp)
            alert("cant create that object hoss!");
      else
            return xmlHttp;
   }

function searchprocess(){ 
    //alert("start");
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
      searchtext=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("searchvalue").value );
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "pages/search_suggestions.php?searchvalue="+searchtext, true);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
      xmlHttp.send(null);
      }else{
         setTimeout('searchprocess()', 1000);
         }
   }


function handleServerResponse(){
    //alert("handle");
   if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            //alert("handle ready");
            if(xmlHttp.status==200 || xmlHttp.status==304){
            //alert("inside");
               xmlResponse=xmlHttp.responseXML;
               xmlDocumentElement=xmlResponse.documentElement;
              message=xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
               document.getElementById("tempo").innerHTML=message;
               setTimeout('searchprocess()', 1000);
         }else{
            alert("Something went wrong!");
            }
      }
   }


// end of JavaScript for search ajax
```

Comment: instead of echo found i should have written echo $suggests

Comment: its not too late to try that :)

Comment: actually i am not getting the answer

Comment: inside the while loop do a print_r($row) and check what you get

Comment: i typed "hel" and i got `Array ( [0] => hello [tag] => hello ) Array ( [0] => hello world [tag] => hello world ) Array ( [0] => hello sanket [tag] => hello sanket ) Array ( [0] => hello, now go and di [tag] => hello, now go and di ) sorry! for hel`

Comment: ok, so basically what is happening is that you are using an ajax call, but having multiple echoes in your php script. What you will need to do is concatenate all your echoes into a string. And then print that string at the end of the code just once.

Comment: i wrote `$suggests=$suggests.$row.',';` in loop and `echo $suggests;` in if still i get undefined... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $sqlresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tag FROM tags where tag like '".$searchvalue."%'");
    $suggests="";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult))
    {
$comma=$suggests?',':'';
        $suggests.=$comma.$row['tag']; 
    }
```

Comment: it worked with only `$suggests.=$row['tag'];`

Answer (score 1):

Since your php script is called by AJAX, instead of individual echoes, concatenate them into a string and echo it once at the end:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$resp = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
$resp .= '<response>';

..and so on... until

$resp .= '</response>';
```

then `echo $response;`